# WinSCP - How to download only folders/files 1 day old while excluding empty folders/files?

Tags: winscp

How do I download all folders/files 1 day old, while excluding empty folders/files?

My current code is getting everything 1 day old, empty or not.  I'm not sure if I can do what's desired with a filemask or not.

```
open sftp://sftpsite/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 hostkeyinfo"

cd /
lcd \\server\destination

    get * -filemask=*>=1D

exit
```

I've tried this code as well, after updated comments, and it tells me: 'Using configured transfer settings different from factory defaults', and it doesn't download the files.  It logs in successfully, but it just doesn't process the files.

```
get -rawtransfersettings ExcludeEmptyDirectories=1 -filemask=">1D" /*
```

Thank you for the help.